# Range object containing all cells of a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a command that creates a `Range` Object containing all cells of a given worksheet.

`Sheets(1).Range("A1:AAZ1000000")` would be a safe bet, but you never know how many rows or columns you might encounter so something like 
`Sheets(1).Range("All")` would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Sheets(1).Cells` returns a `Range` object and when called with no parameters returns a range encompassing all the cells in the sheet.

Comment: Plus one, prefer this, simpler, and probably faster than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

`Sheets(1).EntireRow.EntireColumn` is one way